# Argparse is throwing an error when a bytes argument is passed (Python 3.7)

Tags: argparse, python-3.7

I've written a command with argparse which looks like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("MY_CMD")
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-b', '--binary', default=None, type=bytes)
group.add_argument('-s', '--string', default=None, type=str)
```

In python 2.7 this worked perfectly, but now migrating to Python 3.7, if I try to run it like this:

```
parser.parse_args(['-b', b"hello"])
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python37\lib\argparse.py", line 1749, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\argparse.py", line 1781, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\argparse.py", line 1822, in _parse_known_args
    option_tuple = self._parse_optional(arg_string)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\argparse.py", line 2108, in _parse_optional
    if not arg_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Can anyone point me out how this can be fixed for Python 3? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you testing with a `b"hello"`?  The real commandline input, `sys.argv` will be the standard string type, which in py3 is unicode.  In py2, `bytes` and `str` will be the same, but  not so in py3.  To convert unicode to bytes you use `encode` method, or `bytes` with an encode parameter.

Comment: I use argparse to parse commands received by a sockeserver instance. Those commands can also contain binary data (think about files).

Comment: `argparse` scans the input strings looking for `prefix_chars` (e.g. '-') to decide which to treat as flags and which as arguments.  `b'hello' in '-'` is causing the error.  I can't think of a solution.